# Optional space in angular interpolated string

Tags: angularjs

say I have an angular expression like this:

```
<span>{{vm.name}} {{vm.property|prettyPrint}}</span>
```

Say that property is optional, and may result in empty string. How do I get rid of that no-longer-necessary space after the name? I tried doing something like

```
<span>{{vm.name + ' ' + vm.property|prettyPrint |trim}}</span>
```

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason

```
<span>{{vm.name + ' ' + vm.property|prettyPrint |trim}}</span>
```

doesn't work is because it's applying the prettyPrint filter to everything. Change it to this:

```
<span>{{ (vm.name + ' ' + (vm.property | prettyPrint)) | trim }}</span>
```

Comment: I really should stop working so late - I come up with the most complicated solutions to the simplest of problems. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Place the space inside the `propery` like this

`<span>{{vm.name}}{{' ' + vm.property|prettyPrint}}</span>`

Comment: i thought you said the the `vm.property` might be optional, rephrase your question please :)